# Is it possible to set width of second child to the biggest one in a list of rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, column-width

I Simulate a flex table in a flex column and despite my efforts, I had to give up on table object and use only flex objects.
http://olivier.lahaye1.free.fr/SystemImager/log_table.html

Now I'd like to avoid setting arbitrary width for columns and mimic table column with that will size itself to the biggest of the children in the column.

I'd like to do that in pure CSS (I'm using HTML5)

I'd like that column 1 and 2 get the smallest width without wrapping content.

Right now I'm using a 8em fixed width with is arbitrary.

```css
header > :not(:last-child), .row > :not(:last-child), footer > :not(:last-child) {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 8em;
    text-align: center;
}

header > :last-child, .row > :last-child, footer > :last-child {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div>Tag</div>
    <div>Priority</div>
    <div>Messages (All logs).</div>
 </header>
 <article id="serverData">
     <div class='row'><div>systemimager</div><div>Warning</div><div>Warning message</div></div>
     <div class='row'><div>kernel</div><div>info</div><div>Loading driver e1000e.</div></div>
     <div class='row'><div>systemimager</div><div>Error</div><div>Imaging of host failed.</div></div>
 </article>
```

Is there a way to set width of > :first-child to biggest of all 1st child of header + all .row elements?
(same for > :nth-child(2))

does a syntax allowing for something like:
`width: max((header > :first-child, .row > :first-child, .footer > :first-child).width);` exist?

Comment: your code is missing part of your CSS to demonstrate your issue, but this looks like a typical grid layout, not flex .

Comment: the link provided contains all the code including full css (view source). The problem of grid layout is that the header line will scroll. I need a static header and a static footer and scrollable rows.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/OjMBZg
The trick is to use grid with a header class for the header and stick it with position:sticky;
Then I adapted it to fit my needs and the result is:
http://olivier.lahaye1.free.fr/SystemImager/log_table3.html
Works fine on EDGE and chrome. Minor resize problem on safari (safari bug IMHO). If someone has an idea how to make safari height resize happy when browser window is bigger than required, feel free to post.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Scrollable table in flex column V3.</title>
<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: lightgrey;
}

.wrapper > div {
        background-color: beige;
        color: black;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
        font-size: medium;
}
.wrapper {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
        grid-gap: 2px;
        background-color: #fff;
        max-height:100%;
        overflow:auto;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(3n+1), .wrapper div:nth-child(3n+2) {
        text-align: center;
}

.head, .foot {
        position:sticky;
        top:0;
        font-weight: bold;
}
.foot {
        top:auto;
        bottom:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <section class="flex">
        <p>
        SystemImager v5.0
        <hr style="width: 100%">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="head">Tag</div>
        <div class="head">Priority</div>
        <div class="head">Messages (All messages including kernel messages and sttout+stderr).</div>
            <div>systemimager</div>
            <div>Info</div>
            <div>Command line: si.image-server=10.0.238.84 si.config=testimage.conf acpi=no noapic ip=11.0.42.15::11.0.42.2:255.255.255.0:oscarnode99:eth0:off dns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 rd.vconsole.keymap=fr-mac vga=791 splash si.debug rd.retry=20</div>
            <div>kernel</div>
            <div>info</div>
            <div>Loading driver e100e.</div>
            <div>script 1</div>
            <div>StdErr</div>
            <div>No such file or directory.</div>
            <div>script 2</div>
            <div>StdOut</div>
            <div>I'm script 2.</div>
            <!-- more lines (multiple of 3 divs) -->
            <div>systemimager</div>
            <div>info</div>
            <div>Giving control back to system.</div>
        <div class="foot">Footer with a lot of text.</div>
        <div class="foot">notice</div>
        <div class="foot">I won't use that in SystemImager, but it is here for demonstration.</div>
    </div> <!-- end wrapper -->
    <div style="flex: 1 1 auto"></div>
    <hr style="width: 100%">
    <span>Status line: A clean solution.</span>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```